# PHP else statement not working as it should.. is_numeric and isset

Tags: php, if-statement

In the following If.. else statement, I am trying to see if first, there IS a 4th breadcrumb (URI array 4), and then to see if it is a number..

but both always return true, number, letters, or empty..

can anyone tell me why?

```
// checks the third breadcrumb contained within the breadcrumbs class to see
// if it is an article. Then uses a recursive function to search the first
// and second breadcrumbs to see if they exist within their respective menu
// arrays. finally, if that validates, then the fourth breadcrumb is checked
// to see if it exists (not empty) AND if it is a number.
else 
if (($this->breadcrumbs->getCrumb(3)=='article' && 
     $array_helper->recValueReturn($this->breadcrumbs->getCrumb(2),
     $this->getNavTwo()) && 
     $array_helper->recValueReturn($this->breadcrumbs->getCrumb(1),
     $this->getNavOne())) || ($this->breadcrumbs->getCrumb(4)) && 
     is_numeric($this->breadcrumbs->getCrumb(4))) {
...
```

the following always validates to False:

```
else
if (($this->breadcrumbs->getCrumb(3)=='article'&&
     $array_helper->recValueReturn($this->breadcrumbs->getCrumb(2),
     $this->getNavTwo()) &&
     $array_helper->recValueReturn($this->breadcrumbs->getCrumb(1),
     $this->getNavOne())) &&
     (array_key_exists($this->breadcrumbs->getCrumb(4),
      $this->breadcrumbs->getCrumbs())&&
      is_numeric($this->breadcrumbs->getCrumb(4)))) {
...
```

Comment: what is the format & data in `$this->breadcrumbs->getCrumb(3)` ?

Comment: Have you tried outputting the various values you are checking?

Comment: Have you tried refactoring it using functions with descriptive names so anyone will have a clue what's going on without staring at it for several minutes?

Comment: @Shivan.. just a simple index array of an exploded URI_REQUEST.

Comment: @jim.. doing that now actually.

Comment: @Matt.. the thought has crossed my mind. I'm still learning. This is the best I've come up with so far. Any suggestions? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20795/php-cleaner-way-to-determine-and-load-page-template/20801#comment33378_20801

Comment: @matt.. i've added some comments for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, and for anyone else reading this..

The problem was solved in the BreadCrumbs class itself.

Previous, breadcrumbs had a private array with the exploded URI values. And I retreived a single url index using:

```
public function getCrumb($x) { return $this->breadcrumbs[$x] }
```

But if i modify this getter directly to include an isset:

```
public function getCrumb($x) {
    if (isset($this->breadcrumbs[$x])) {
        return $this->breadcrumbs[$x];
    } else {
            return null;
    }
}
```

and then use the first *else..if* in the OP.. problem solved. It works.